# Single login session for django application

Tags: django, vue.js, session, django-rest-framework

I have Web application with VUE as frontend stack and Django DRF as backend stack I want to enable the feature that if someone is login from one system he/she can't login from other system unless and until logout from previous session is there any proper mechanism to do so

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR I wouldn't even bother trying. But if you want: use websockets and keep track of the number of users connecting to a single endpoint.

It's not fool-proof since these are just tokens which means anyone with a terminal and curl can still access whatever REST API you have.

---

I think you have to understand how most people are using Vue, React, and other JS frameworks with Django. They're most likely not using SessionMiddleware and using something like [djangorestframework-simplejwt](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/djangorestframework-simplejwt) (disclaimer: I help maintain it, and I've got a slight bias against JS frameworks + Django).

The problem lies in how authorization works, namely stateful and stateless. In your case with these token authentication methods, you've got stateless tokens that are verified only by signing, and not by anything backed by a database/cache on the server. So we don't actually know how many tabs the user has opened.

In SimpleJWT, we have something like token Blacklist, but it won't really help that much.

So the solution is to use websockets. You can keep track of the number of users connecting to a single endpoint (after authorization and authentication. You can use something like Django channels) by creating a cache key (backed by a service like Redis or Memcached in production, local can use memory/dummy) and incrementing and decrementing by the number of connections and disconnections.

That way, you have something on the server to backup all these claims.

It's not fool-proof since these are just tokens which means anyone with a terminal and curl can still access whatever REST API you have.

Comment: Actually, I want to implement the feature where if a user is signed in from one system and without logout if he tries to login from another system then a message should be pop out that only one login is allowed.

Comment: Ok... well if you think about the websockets idea, after authorization, determine if the first client/any other session is not closed yet. If not, then send a message to the second client and close the websocket connection. On your client side, when you receive that message, Vue should show that message.